# Is that possible to use SharedPreferences for File variable? And how to use it?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to save a `File` variable using `SharedPreferences`. All i know is use `setString(key, value)` with `value` is `base64Encode(FILE.readAsBytesSync())`. So it will look like this

```
class SaveFilePref extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SaveFilePrefState createState() => _SaveFilePrefState();
}

class _SaveFilePrefState extends State<SaveFilePref> {
  File file; 
    
  savePref() async{      
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState((){
      //let's say the file variable already have a value of File(like image or something)
      pref.setString('file', base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync())); 
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}
```

But, if the code above is possible to do, then **how to get the preferences and save the value to another File variable?(not just `String`)**

Comment: You can't store files on sharedpreferences. I think you can saving the image in local storage and save the file path in sharedpreferences or pass the File directly to the widget you want to will help

Comment: Hmm okay, thankyou